# Validating a Date in Java exactly like Oracle does in TO_DATE()

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper, to-date

I have to Validate a date in Java to check if it is in correct format and correct value.

If I use SimpleDateformat Class, it will make wrong date valid as well because if a month is given as 14 it will add 1 year to the Year part.

However in Oracle it will indivisually check if Month , Date , Hour , Minute etc is correct.

E.g. in Oracle

```
TO_DATE(20141511 , 'YYYYMMDD')
```

will give error that the MONTH i.e. 15 is incorrect

But in Java

```
Date d = "YYYYMMDD".parse("20141511");
```

will be valid because it will count it as 2015+3 months.

So, how can I validate a date in Java exactly like Oracle does in its TO_DATE function?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question, you could use [`DateFormat.setLenient(false)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#setLenient%28boolean%29). Per the JavaDoc,

> Specify whether or not date/time parsing is to be lenient ... With strict parsing, inputs must match this object's format.

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
df.setLenient(false);
try {
  Date d = df.parse("20141511");
} catch (ParseException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Does not allow the invalid date to parse and throws

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "20141511"
```

Answer (score 0):

None of these solutions account Oracle settings for the date format.  A more global solution using oracle.sql.Date and exceptions:

```
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import oracle.sql.DATE;

 public void validateDate  (String dateString,  String nlsDateFormat, String nlsDateLanguage) throws ParseException, SQLException {
  if (dateString == null) {
      throw new ParseException("Date parameter not entered.", 0);
  } else {
      try {
        DATE.fromText(dateString,  nlsDateFormat, nlsDateLanguage); //not implemented in every ojdbc driver, works with ojbdbc6.jar
      }  catch (SQLException e) {
          if (!e.getMessage().contains("Unimplemented")) {
              throw new SQLException (e);
          }                       
      }
  }
```

}

(I discovered some drivers couldn't even handle this.. so validation is bypassed if oracle.sql.DATE is not implemented)/  To get session variables for NLS_FORMAT and NLS_LANGUAGE:

private String getDateNlsFmt() throws SQLException {

```
    String nlsDateFormat;
    String sqlStmt =
          "SELECT value nlsDateFormat                     "
        + "  FROM nls_session_parameters                      "
        + "  WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT'            ";

    QueryStatement q = new QueryStatement(conn, sqlStmt);
    q.open();
    if (!q.eof()) {
      nlsDateFormat      = q.getString("nlsDateFormat");          
    }
    q.close();
    return nlsDateFormat;
  }


 private String getDateNlsLang() throws SQLException {

    String  nlsDateLanguage;
    String sqlStmt =
          "SELECT value nlsDateLanguage                       "
        + "  FROM nls_session_parameters                      "
        + "  WHERE parameter = 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE'            ";

    QueryStatement q = new QueryStatement(conn, sqlStmt);
    q.open();
    if (!q.eof()) {
      nlsDateLanguage    = q.getString("nlsDateLanguage");        
    }
    q.close();
    return nlsDateLanguage;
  }
```